"dual-mode" helper which opens _both_ .tar.gz _and_ .zip archives confusedly saved under the same file extension (say, `.yuppie`)?
So someone at my company years ago decided it was a good idea to create a company internal package format, say "yuppie" for yunified package.  And that can randomly be tgz or zip archives.  Don't ask.
Now I need some 'yuppie-mode' function that dispatches to either archive-mode or jka-compr and then tar-mode.
Any ideas?  suggestions how to solve this?
currently I'm creating symlinks from file --mime-type output and then open the file, but that is a hack, not a solution :-/

It might make it easier for helpers if you gave an example of each type of input and desired output.
